# Preserve commits in history while rebasing

Tags: git

Having this commits history

```
A-B-C-D-E-F
```

What I want to achieve after changes:

```
A(includes D as fixup)-B(same with E)-C(F)
```

What I'm doing:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

Then I'm manually  rearranging commits in this way:

```
pick aaaaaaa A
fixup dddddd D
pick bbbbbb B
fixup eeeeeee E
pick ccccccc C
fixup ffffff F
```

After prompting wq git asking me to solve the conflicts, choose commit messages and `git rebase --continue`. Everything is looking fine, but instead of `A-B-C` history I'm getting just a single `A` commit(final content of which is correct). So how do I preserve B and C commits as a part of history?

Comment: What does _"includes D as fixup"_ mean? What's a fixup? Do you mean you'd like to squash A and D?

Comment: It means that commit D maded as this: `commit --fixup aaaaaaa`

Comment: Did you fix the conflicts and run `git rebase --continue`? If not, you're still *in the middle of the rebase*. With a modern Git, `git status` will tell you this, but if you have an ancient (1.7ish) Git due to ancient CentOS software for instance, it might not.